# Not Able To delete data from SQLITE Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

What am i doing wrong here?? i have three table in database, and i need to delete all data from them.

```
-(void)deleteAllDataFromTables
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.databasePath);

    int result = sqlite3_open([appDelegate.databasePath UTF8String], &db);
    if(result == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"deleteCalled");
        const char *deleteData = "delete from CustomerNumberTable";
        int outcome = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteData, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(outcome == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int res = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if(res == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"deleted from Customer Table");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"not able to execute step statement");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"not deleted from Customer Table");
            NSLog(@"the error is %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        const char *deleteData2 = "delete from KeyCodeTable";
        int outcome2 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteData2, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(outcome2 == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int res = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if(res == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"deleted from KeyCodeTable");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"not able to execute step statement");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"not deleted from KeyCodeTable");
            NSLog(@"the error is %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        const char *deleteData3 = "delete from SRNumberTable";
        int outcome3 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteData3, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(outcome3 == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int res = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if(res == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"deleted from SRNumberTable");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"not able to execute step statement");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"not deleted from SRNumberTable");
            NSLog(@"the error is %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not able to open database for deleting");
    }
}
```

On console, i am getting

```
Application[54974:a0b] deleteCalled
2014-01-03 16:12:55.442 Application[54974:a0b] deleted from Customer Table
2014-01-03 16:12:55.443 Application[54974:a0b] deleted from KeyCodeTable
2014-01-03 16:12:55.445 Application[54974:a0b] deleted from SRNumberTable
```

But when i am opening the database in on mac, the data is intact there..!! What is wrong with my code?? why isn't the data getting deleted??

Comment: Maybe you must commit your transaction

Comment: and close the database.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, nobody really knows.  Tell us where the database is on the device.  Tell us if you use transactions.

Comment: Are you checking on correct database ? Also where is your database located ? On main bundle or documents directory ?

Comment: it is located in doc directory

Comment: I am not using transactions @trojanfoe

Comment: @Coder123 Are you using device or simulator? both are having diff path for document directory.

Comment: i am using simulator now.. The database is being formed on mac.. I can open it and see that the data is still there, but the console shows that data has been deleted successfully.. @Apurv

Comment: Go to /Users/user/Library/Application Support. Here you will find directories of your OS version. Open it and check for you application inside it. In your app folder, you will find document directory where the updated db will be placed.

Comment: i know that @Apurv.. i am seeing that everytime i make changes in DB. it still shows data. It is not getting deleted

Comment: This happen when you copy the db into document directory when the app run for the first time. To take the effect of updated db, delete the app from simulator and install run the project again. It will have updated copy.

Comment: guyz.. it is working fine on real device.. this problem was on mac only..

Answer (score 2):

I think you are copying your database from bundle to documents directory. So, the updated database will be present in documents directory. You seems to look the database from your workspace which is never going to be of updated one.

Answer (score 2):

Your code opens database with `sqlite3_open()`, but does not close it using `sqlite3_close()`. This means that your database is probably still in open transaction, and quite possibly has 2 files: one is main `database.db`, and journal file `database.db-journal` which contains uncommitted intent to delete your tables.

You should make sure that your application closes database before you copy database file from the device to the host. At the very least, copy both main database AND journal file as one set. It is still likely to have consistency issues, but you should see your changes.

Comment: Transactions have to explicitly began don't they and I don't see that in the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

Try instead of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to `sqlite3_exec`. This working fine for me.

Just Ref:

```
char *errMsg;
    const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Db OPened ");
        NSString *queryLists = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from Table_name"];
        const char *query_stmt = [queryLists UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_exec(database, query_stmt,  NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
            != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Error %s", errMsg);
            NSLog(@"Table Not Deleted");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1st thing Don't write same functionality code repeatedly in place create one function that delete all data from given table name,

2nd make sure you are looking at correct sqlite file in mac.

look this,

```
-(void)deleteAllData
{
[self deleteTable: CustomerNumberTable];
[self deleteTable: SRNumberTable];
[self deleteTable: KeyCodeTable];


}

-(void)deleteTable:(NSString *)table;
{
    const char *dbpath=[appDelegate.databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &dtdb)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        const char *qry=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from %@",table] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(dtdb, qry, -1, &stmt, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
NSLog(@"%@ Table data deleted",table);            
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        sqlite3_close(dtdb);
    }    
}
```

Comment: 3rd: Don't repeatedly open/close the database.  Instead store/pass the database handle about.

Comment: @trojanfoe: totally agree, just giving general idea.